# First use of glossaries' acronym using custom key (for other grammatical construct)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, grammar

I'm using glosseries to manage my acronyms and added/defined the genitive form of a word using

```
\glsaddkey*{gen}%key
{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}XXXGEN}% default
{\glsentrygen}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentrygen}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsgen}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glsgen}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSgen}% command analogous to \GLStext
```

and added an entry:

```
\newacronym[%
   gen={Signal-Rausch-Verhältnisses},
]{SNR}{SNR}{Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis}
```

Then I use it in my TeX-file like

```
… in Abhängigkeit des \glsgen{SNR} …
… für hohe \gls{SNR} …
```

**The problem** is as follows:
It SHOULD translate to

```
… in Abhängigkeit des Signal-Rausch-Verhältnisses (SNR) …
… für hohe SNR …
```

but actually translates to

```
… in Abhängigkeit des Signal-Rausch-Verhältnisses …
… für hohe Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis (SNR) …
```

Any ideas how to trigger the acronym-abbrevation / making use of the first-use flag?

When I use the basic form/gls-command everything works like expected.
(similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316127/first-use-with-custom-key-in-glossaries-acronym) but without any answers or examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the test for first use yourself and then act accordingly. And use `glsunset` to unset first use.

```
\newcommand{\GENglspostlinkhook}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{ (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})}\glsunset \glslabel}
\newcommand{\glsgenx}[1]{%
  {\let\glspostlinkhook \GENglspostlinkhook\glsgen{#1}}
}
```

and then use

```
in Abhängigkeit des \glsgenx{SNR}
```

Or maybe swap `\glsgen` and `\glsgenx`.

If you want the (SNR) to have a hyperlink to the acronym, then use:

```
\newcommand{\GENglspostlinkhook}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{ (\glshyperlink{\glslabel})}\glsunset \glslabel}
```

Comment: I have made a correction for the case when the label and the abbreviation are different (e.g. `\newacronym[gen={Signal-Rausch-Verhältnisses}]{snr}{SNR}{Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis}`. It should then print `(SNR)` and not `(snr)`